# JMeter: Unzip request while recording

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to decompress HTTP requests while recording them with JMeter (v5.0)? The request body contains zipped (gzip) JSON data.

The current solution is very cumbersome. We are extracting the unzipped request body from the browser (Internet Explorer / private mode).

We are using the developer tools to set a breakpoint in the JavaScript file "compress.js" and start the request to get to it. The body tag contains the JSON data. We copy it to a text editor and replace backslash+quotation-mark with quotation-mark. In the last step, we replace real values by JMeter user-defined variables.

Comment: any feedback on answer ? If useful you should accept it and upvote. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as of JMeter 5.0.

See this enhancement request:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61748

You may want to test using BURP proxy to decompress request:

- https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/options/http